# add element add two place in html

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.querySelector('#submit').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.merge').forEach((select) => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#text-get').value;
    document.querySelector('.merge').append(option);
  })
  return false;
};
```

```html
<select id="task" class="merge">

</select>

<select id="task2" class="merge">

</select>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="text-get">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

I would like to add option in both the drop down but with same input tag 
   value.

There is something wrong with JavaScript code.it is not adding to any.

Comment: Use `select.append(option)` instead of `document.querySelector('.merge').append(option)`

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Try this way :

```js
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('.merge'), // Caching elements so the DOM won't be queried constantly
      input = document.querySelector('#text-get');

document.querySelector('#submit').onclick = () => {
  selects.forEach(select => {
    let option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML = input.value;
    select.append(option)
  });
  return false;
};
```

```html
<select id="task" class="merge">

</select>

<select id="task2" class="merge">

</select>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="text-get">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```